# Hello, How to Update my Drupal 7 to Drupal 9 like a staff?

Tags: drupal

I see drupal is not famous here. Maybe can help me upgrade drupal 7 to drupal 9. I need help with how to update the Drupal 7 module and Drupal 7 theme too to be compatible with Drupal 9 how? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do the update from D7 to D9 in an automatic way. The procedure is tricky and could cause big problems because of big changes in the core logic from D7 to D9.

As the [official guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-9-or-later) suggests the procedure would be:

1. Create an empty D8
2. Migrate configurations & content types from D7 to D8

Once you have migrated to D8 you can perform the "automatic" migration via Composer to D9 (you can find the steps [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/drupal-8-and-higher))

And i add a suggestion: after using the `drush upddb` install the module [entity update](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_update) in order to update the entity automatically. Once is installed just run `drush en entity_update -y` to update the entities.
Updating is sometimes complicated and often requires custom interventions on the database to correct entities.
To check the status of the work have always a look to the page `/admin/reports/status` to see if everything is okay.

NB: I also suggest you to update PHP to 8.0 version and leave MySQL to 5.*.*